# GRASS importing same-name rasters fails

Tags: raster, grass-gis, import

I have NED elevation data in 3 rasters. (That's how it downloaded from USGS NED page.) The files are named `61471006`, `61471006_2`, and `61471006_3`. I succeeded in using the GRASS GUI and menu [File-> Import raster data -> Common import formats] to import the first raster, by browsing into the file folder named `61471006` and selecting the file "w001001.adf". However, I need to also bring in the `.adf` files from `61471006_2` and `61471006_3`, but within their respective folders, the `.adf` files are named the same as the `.adf` file in the first folder. Therefore GRASS does not let me bring in the same-name files. 
I tried re-naming the `.adf` files in `61471006_2` and `61471006_3`, but then GRASS put up the error message that the file type was not recognized.
How can I get these ostensibly same-name rasters to all three be imported into my GRASS map? (Each raster covers a different geographic area within the overall area.)

Answer (score 1):

In the GRASS location, files must (of course) have different names.
In the "Common import formats" menu, after having selected the file to be imported, you can double click on the "Name for GRASS map (editable)" name (right column) and assign a new, unique name.

See also the screenshots in http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Importing_data

Comment: @Catlike please accept this answer if it solved your problem

Comment: @underdark - It didn't work for me; I think I have my software configured wrong, because it didn't let me follow the steps above. I need to tinker with the settings, I suppose...